# Coverage + multiprocessing problems

Tags: python, multiprocessing, code-coverage, coverage.py

I've faced problems with using of coverage module with multiprocessing. I know that there is a bunch of other issues here about it, but they did not help me at all.

The idea is to use multiprocessing.Process with coverage, but using "process_startup" it fails with a weird error, and of course coverage calculation does not work.

I've created a simple code snippet to reproduce the problem.

Files used:

```
main.py
pack\
--__init__.py
--f1.py
```

main.py:

```
from coverage import Coverage

from pack.f1 import function_entered
from multiprocessing import Process


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cov = Coverage(config_file="coverage.ini")

    cov.erase()
    cov.start()

    process = Process(target=function_entered)
    process.start()
    process.join()

    cov.stop()
    cov.save()
    cov.combine()

    cov.html_report(directory="coverage_report")

    cov.report()
```

f1.py:

```
import os

from coverage import process_startup


def function_entered():
    os.environ["COVERAGE_PROCESS_START"] = "coverage.ini"
    process_startup()

    print('function checked')
```

Result:

```
function checked
self._collectors:
  <Collector at 0x1b6ca9db940: CTracer>
                      <module> : <string>:1
                    spawn_main : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py:116
                         _main : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py:129
                    _bootstrap : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\multiproc.py:32
                         start : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py:575
               _init_for_start : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py:483
                      __init__ : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\collector.py:114
  <Collector at 0x1b6ca9dbac0: CTracer>
                      <module> : <string>:1
                    spawn_main : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py:116
                         _main : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py:129
                    _bootstrap : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\multiproc.py:42
                    _bootstrap : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\multiprocessing\process.py:315
                           run : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\multiprocessing\process.py:108
              function_entered : C:\projects\temp\cov_test\pack\f1.py:8
               process_startup : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py:1215
                         start : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py:575
               _init_for_start : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py:483
                      __init__ : C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\collector.py:114
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 129, in _main
    return self._bootstrap(parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\multiproc.py", line 46, in _bootstrap
    cov.stop()
  File "C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py", line 599, in stop
    self._collector.stop()
  File "C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\collector.py", line 349, in stop
    assert self._collectors[-1] is self, (
AssertionError: Expected current collector to be <Collector at 0x1b6ca9db940: CTracer>, but it's <Collector at 0x1b6ca9dbac0: CTracer>
C:\Users\Evgenii_Kozlov\Miniconda3\envs\coverage_test_2\lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py:793: CoverageWarning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
  self._warn("No data was collected.", slug="no-data-collected")
Name               Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
----------------------------------------------------
pack\__init__.py       0      0      0      0   100%
pack\f1.py             6      4      0      0    33%
pack\f2.py             2      2      0      0     0%
----------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                  8      6      0      0    25%

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Conda environment:

```
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2022.3.29            haa95532_0
certifi                   2020.6.20          pyhd3eb1b0_3
coverage                  6.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
libffi                    3.4.2                h604cdb4_1
openssl                   1.1.1n               h2bbff1b_0
pip                       21.2.4          py310haa95532_0
python                    3.10.4               hbb2ffb3_0
setuptools                61.2.0          py310haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.38.2               h2bbff1b_0
tk                        8.6.11               h2bbff1b_0
tzdata                    2022a                hda174b7_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2             py310haa95532_2
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
zlib                      1.2.11               hbd8134f_5
```

coverage.ini

```
[run]
branch = True
parallel = True
concurrency = multiprocessing

source =
    pack


[report]
exclude_lines =
    def __repr__
    .raise .
    if __name__ == .__main__.:
```

Comment: I'm trying it on Windows, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: Why are you using the Coverage API here?  Why not just run your program with the `coverage run` command?

Comment: @NedBatchelder, what problem does your solution solve? It gives the same result. And why should not I use Coverage API?

Comment: I didn't know if the explicit API calls were adding to the problem, and generally you don't need the API explicitly, so it's simpler to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Although [coverage changelog](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html) from Version 4.1b1 — 2016-01-10 says that multiprocessing works on Windows, I was not able to run in correctly.

My solution is based on a slightly changed code from [there](https://gist.github.com/andreycizov/ee59806a3ac6955c127e511c5e84d2b6).

```
class CoverageProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, *args, config_file=None, **kwargs):
        self._config_file = config_file
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        if self._config_file:
            cov = Coverage(config_file=self._config_file, data_suffix=os.getpid(), auto_data=True)
            cov._warn_no_data = False
            cov.start()

            try:
                super().run()
            finally:
                cov.stop()
                cov.save()
        else:
            super().run()
```

So you use *CoverageProcess* instead of *Process* and manually pass config path to it.
Far from ideal, but works for me.
Also I noticed that in this case running *Coverage* from parent process results in "CoverageWarning: No data was collected." warning, even if you disabled it via *cov._warn_no_data = False*. But the result is correct.

**Important note**: using Path object that is passed in Coverage object (path to config file) leads to a weird error "AttributeError: _cached_cparts", that can't even be googled. Use raw string instead.